# How to optimize Spark Job processing S3 files into Hive Parquet Table

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to Spark distributed development. I'm attempting to optimize my existing Spark job which takes up to 1 hour to complete.

**Infrastructure**:

- EMR [10 instances of r4.8xlarge (32 cores, 244GB)]
- Source Data: 1000 .gz files in S3 (~30MB each)
- Spark Execution Parameters [Executors: 300, Executor Memory: 6gb, Cores: 1]

In general, the Spark job performs the following:

```
private def processLines(lines: RDD[String]): DataFrame = {
    val updatedLines = lines.mapPartitions(row => ...)
    spark.createDataFrame(updatedLines, schema)
}

// Read S3 files and repartition() and cache()
val lines: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext
    .textFile(pathToFiles, numFiles) 
    .repartition(2 * numFiles) // double the parallelism
    .cache()

val numRawLines = lines.count()

// Custom process each line and cache table
val convertedLines: DataFrame = processLines(lines)
convertedRows.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_tbl")
spark.sqlContext.cacheTable("temp_tbl")
val numRows = spark.sql("select count(*) from temp_tbl").collect().head().getLong(0)

// Select a subset of the data
val myDataFrame = spark.sql("select a, b, c from temp_tbl where field = 'xxx' ")

// Define # of parquet files to write using coalesce
val numParquetFiles = numRows / 1000000
var lessParts = myDataFrame.rdd.coalesce(numParquetFiles)
var lessPartsDataFrame = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(lessParts, myDataFrame.schema)
lessPartsDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView('my_view')

// Insert data from view into Hive parquet table
spark.sql("insert overwrite destination_tbl 
           select * from my_view")    
lines.unpersist()
```

The app reads all S3 files => repartitions to twice the amount of files => caches the RDD => custom processes each line => creates a temp view/cache table => counts the num rows => selects a subset of the data => decrease the amount of partitions => creates a view of the subset of data => inserts to hive destination table using the view => unpersist the RDD.

I am not sure why it takes a long time to execute. Are the spark execution parameters incorrectly set or is there something being incorrectly invoked here?

Comment: Can you provide some metrics from Spark UI on your job execution ?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before looking at the metrics, I would try the following change to your code.

```
private def processLines(lines: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  lines.mapPartitions(row => ...)
}

val convertedLinesDf = spark.read.text(pathToFiles)
    .filter("field = 'xxx'")
    .cache()

val numLines = convertedLinesDf.count() //dataset get in memory here, it takes time        
// Select a subset of the data, but it will be fast if you have enough memory
// Just use Dataframe API
val myDataFrame = convertedLinesDf.transform(processLines).select("a","b","c")

//coalesce here without converting to RDD, experiment what best
myDataFrame.coalesce(<desired_output_files_number>)
  .write.option(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .saveAsTable("destination_tbl")
```

- Caching is useless if you don't count the number of rows. And it will take some memory and add some GC pressure
- Caching table may consume more memory and add more GC pressure
- Converting Dataframe to RDD is costly as it implies ser/deser operations
- Not sure what you trying to do with : `val numParquetFiles = numRows / 1000000` and repartition(`2 * numFiles`). With your setup, 1000 files of 30MB each will give you 1000 partitions. It could be fine like this. Calling repartition and coalesce may trigger a shuffling operation which is costly. (Coalesce may not trigger a shuffle)

Tell me if you get any improvements !

Comment: Hi @Nonontb , thanks so much for the reply. I will try that out.



(a) Looks like instead of using `spark.sparkContext.textFile(pathToFiles, numFiles)`, I'll try using `spark.read.text(pathToFiles)`

Comment: (b) I used repartition(2 * numFiles) to try to increase the partitions to 2000 in hopes that this would increase the parallelism and speed it up. I'll try removing this.

Comment: (c) Ah, so I forgot to mention that I am actually planning to call *count()* on the source lines: RDD[String]. I edited the post to include it. Should I still remove the  cache() call and also the unpersist() call on the RDD?

Comment: (d) Reasoning for calling coalesce(numParquetFiles) was to decrease the number of parquet files written to S3. I noticed that if there were a lot files being written, it seemed to take longer. I'll try removing coalesce() call, but if I do, it seems it will write 1000 parquet files into the s3.

Comment: (e) I'm interested in calling my custom processLines() function which does mapPartitions() on each of the lines (RDD[String]). It will be doing some manipulation there to each of the lines. Is it ok to continue to use processLines(lines: RDD[String])?

Comment: r(b) It may help if an executor has not enough memory to handle one partition, so you repartition but => shuffle, you increase executor memory if you have some available

Comment: r(c) If you keep the count(), `.cache()` may be useful as the `select(...)` and `filter(...)` will occur on a memory dataset. if you can put `filter(...)` right after the `read`in this case, it is better to cache less data

Comment: r(e) yes, you can but it is useless to read RDD and create a DataFrame when you can work directly on dataframe. There won't be a big impact tough

Comment: r(d) you can keep the coalesce on the dataframe API if you want, it should not shuffle the dataset as you reduce the partition. But converting to rdd to call coalesce on RDD api cost you ser/deser operations.

Comment: Could it be that my spark execution parameters are incorrectly set? (Executors: 300, Executor Memory: 6gb, Executor Cores: 1)

Comment: Generally, should the number of partitions used be equal or less than the number of executors specified when the spark job is submitted?

Comment: Reason is because I am using 300 as the value for number of executors and sometimes this application may process 1000 files or 300 files or 100 files or 50 files.

Comment: And the number of files here seems to define the number of partitions when spark does the read on the text

Comment: You seem to be correctly set but I dont know your use case in details. Spark recommands : number of partitions = 2-3x nb cores https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html. (check level of parallelism). Anyway, It is a good start